# Why soup. find_all() only returning one result

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, element

I'm scraping some information and below is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.privateproperty.com.ng/property-for-sale"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div', class_="similar-listings-item sponsored-listing")

for result in results:
    Title = result.find('div', class_= "similar-listings-info").text.replace('\n','')
    location = result.find( class_= "listings-location").text.replace('\n','')
    Price = result.find('div', class_= "similar-listings-price").text.replace('\n','')
    

info = (Title, location, Price)
print(info)
```

Why does this line

```
results = soup.find_all('div', class_="similar-listings-item sponsored-listing")
```

return only the 1st element?

Comment: `Soup.find_all()` returns a list.  If you want a list-of-lists, you'll have to process those results and build it yourself.

Comment: Thank you John, please how can I do that?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking me to write your program for you...

Comment: Yes John Gordon, please could you help me with better language that enable me get the list of lists of the above function.

Comment: what's the html you're working with, and what output do you want to extract from it? the question is quite vague, but maybe you want to do something like [this](https://pastebin.com/ZnZ7xM6u) with [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does this line
>
> ```py
> results = soup.find_all('div', class_="similar-listings-item sponsored-listing")
> ```
>
> return only the 1st element?

I'm getting  [2 elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx4e7.png), but maybe you're only *seeing* the last result because  the *`info=...print(info)`* lines are *after* the loop instead of **inside** it. Indent them to print every the **result** from inside the loop.

---

If your issue is that you want *all* the listings, you should note that **only the [sponsored listings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GeKh.png)** have the *`sponsored-listing`* class. To get all the listings, you can try using

```py
results = soup.find_all('div', {'class': "similar-listings-item"}) ## OR
# results = soup.select('div.similar-listings-item')
```

<sub>[Use `soup.select('div.similar-listings-item:not(.sponsored-listing)')` if you only want *un*sponsored listings. Check out how to use [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) with [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) for more details.]</sub>

---

> I want to extract list of lists from the (variable)

which variable? If you want list of all the `Title`, `location`, `Price` for each `result`, initiate an empty list [like `infoList`] before the loop, then indent `info=...` to include it in the list, and [append](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/append) `info` to `infoList` at the end of the loop (but still **in** the loop). Something like

```py
infoList = []
for result in results:
    Title = result.find('div', class_= "similar-listings-info").text.replace('\n','')
    location = result.find( class_= "listings-location").text.replace('\n','')
    Price = result.find('div', class_= "similar-listings-price").text.replace('\n','')

    info = (Title, location, Price) # this is a tuple btw, so 
    # infoList.append(info) # --> list of tuples
    infoList.append([Title, location, Price]) # --> list of lists
    # print(info) # will print for every result
print(info) # will print ONLY the LAST result
```

---

Btw, it's not very safe to chain `.find` and `.text` like that. If `.find` doesn't find any thing, then an [error will be raised](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75276178/6146136) when trying to get `.text`. To be more cautious, you should check that find returned something first.

<sub>You could use my [`selectForList`](https://pastebin.com/ZnZ7xM6u) function like *`infoList = [selectForList(result, ['div.similar-listings-info', 'p.listings-location', 'div.similar-listings-price']) for result in results]`* or [since you want to remove the `\n`s and also if you don't want to use CSS selectors] use a variation of it:</sub>

```py
def get_min_text(containerTag, elName, classAttr, defaultVal=None):
    el = containerTag.find(elName, class_=classAttr)
    if el is None: return defaultVal
    return ' '.join(el.get_text(' ').split()) # split+join minimizes whitespace

results = soup.find_all('div', {'class': "similar-listings-item"}) 
infoList = [[get_min_text(result, *c[:3]) for c in [
    ('div', 'similar-listings-info'), # Title
    ('p', 'listings-location'), # Location
    ('div', 'similar-listings-price') # Price
]] for result in results]
```

[image: op]